# Android Button Issues

Tags: android

So I'm trying to write this simple program in Android that on Button click changes the text Displayed. Only 1 Button, would pull a String from an Array.

```
IE 
text ="don't push button"
user *pushes Button*
text= "I Said Don't Push Button"
etc.
```

I've searched here, and about a million other resources for the correct implementation and have followed them and still get nothing. Every time I click the button it does nothing. 
with my `String[]`, i have an int that is assigned to be Random so that it won't always be the exact same `String` pulled first

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {    
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnew);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView rtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rtext.setText(lines.pickline);
                                    }
    });
}
```

Any help as to where/what i am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `lines.pickline`?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to declare the TextView outside the onClick() Method in the OnClickListener{}, Try The following:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

boolean buttonClickedOnce;
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView rtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rtext.setText("don't push button");

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnew);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClickedOnce = true;
            rtext.setText("I Said Don't Push Button");
                                    }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: How would that change anything? It will find the same view whether inside or outside.

Comment: @Apoorv ... Ridiculous, if you write it inside the OnClickView(), then it will try to instantiate a *new* text view every time you *click* the Button name button and sets the text lines.pickline, hope you have managed to add some toggle so that the text changes next time you click the Button.

Comment: Agreed that is bad practice, but what you are suggesting does not solve the OP's prblem

Comment: To solve the problem @M88K Needs to put in the logic to change the text in onClick() method, which he claims to pull from a string[] array. Neither has he set any variable to tell android to pick next text from the array... as per the code now... it should show only one text on each click ... the text he cliams to be in the **lines.pickline**

Comment: OK so i got rid of my "lines" class and decided to follow the advice here.
I put the string[], and the textView creation in the 'on create' then put the random in the 'on click' so that it will generate a new number on each click. However the click still isn't working correctly. Doesn't do anything still. no new line, no crash. nothing.

Comment: @M88K I've edited the code, hope it works as you expected. Or do you wish... the longer the user keeps the button in pressed state the text should be "I said don't push the button"?

Comment: I don't know i'm about to give up and go back to C#, now it's saying it needs the main to be abstract or to implement the abstract OnClick(view v) in the click listener, which it already has. I knew there was a reason I got away from java

Comment: Oh Common @M88K you are doing a great job pal... Learning new language is really a challenge, and you are performing well... hey as compared to java... Android doesn't require main class.... it's execution starts from the onCreate() Method..

Comment: Well i seem to have gotten that figured out(button was working on last test), I went back and added some more Strings to the String[] and now I get an error "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" go back and delete the added [] values, and still the same issue.
It's not as if this is some kind of in depth program, this would take all of 5 minutes to do in C#, VB, and C++. Why does android have to be so stupid.

Comment: OK.. Then... Don't curse android for it... It's an OS... uses Java... You Need to learn how these things are done in java... that's the only difference and also the way out for you.

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answer's comments, it is probably safer to declare your TextView globally or at least outside of the clickListener...

... but the real thing you seemed to be missing was some type of logic to determine how to put the random text in...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate the Text View
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Set Our Array Of Strings
    String[] lines = new String[5]; 
    lines[0] = "john";
    lines[1] = "paul";
    lines[2] = "george";
    lines[3] = "ringo";
    lines[4] = "the other guy";

    // Instantiate The Button
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Generate Random Number
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNum = random.nextInt(lines.length);

            // Set the Text from the appropriate line
            text.setText(lines[randomNum]);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that helps, and answers the question !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function inside on click with a if condition if button pressed to set a desired text.
   `onClick()
    if(button.isPressed())
    {
     setText();
    }`